# Free Memory from Vector of Objects (not ptrs to the objects)

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, memory-leaks, g++

I declared the vector:

```
vector<Object> my_vect;
```

and I pushed some objects into it like

```
my_vect.push_back(*(new Object()));
```

I know it would have been simple if I were to declare a vector of pointers, but this is crucial to my code.

I tried using

```
my_vect.clear()
```

But to no avail.

Moreover, I also tried getting the pointers to the objects like:

```
vector<*Object> new_my_vect;

for(int i = 0; i < my_vect.size(); i++)
{
    new_my_vect.push_back(&my_vect[i]);
}

for(int i = 0; i < new_my_vect.size(); i++)
{
    delete new_my_vect[i];
}
```

But I get an "`free(): invalid pointer:`" error.

Thank-you,

Comment: Why do you think you need `new` here: `my_vect.push_back(*(new Object()));` actually?

Comment: I ended up just using my_vect.push_back(Object()). I'm new to C++ so I wasn't too sure whether the object needed to be stored on the heap. So just a follow up question: even though I am using the object out of scope (by storing it in the vector), why does it work out fine? Doesn't it get overriden on the stack by something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding objects as follows

```
vector<Object> my_vect;

my_vect.emplace_back();
```

or

```
my_vect.push_back(Object());
```

I would not recommend getting pointers to the objects within the vector, as if anything causes the vector to re-allocate those pointers will be invalidated as the underlying array will be copied elsewhere.

Comment: Or `vector<Object> my_vect(n);`.

Comment: Thank-you so much for your answer. I ended up just using my_vect.push_back(Object()). I'm new to C++ so I wasn't too sure whether the object needed to be stored on the heap. So just a follow up question: even though I am using the object out of scope (by storing it in the vector), why does it work out fine? Doesn't it get overriden on the stack by something else?

Answer (score 1):

> *(new Object())

This is a memory leak. It creates a new object on the heap, dereferences it, makes a copy (unless vector::push_back is using move semantics) and then leaks the memory reserved by the heap allocation.

> vector<*Object> new_my_vect;
>
> for(int i = 0; i < my_vect.size(); i++)
>      {
>          new_my_vect.push_back(&my_vect[i]);
>      }
>
> for(int i = 0; i < new_my_vect.size(); i++)
>      {
>          delete new_my_vect[i];
>      }

This is taking the address of the objects stored within the vector themselves. This is definitely guaranteed to not be the same address as the address of the object you passed into the vector. A vector can reallocate and rearrange it's internal memory at will. It is only safe to take the address of an object in the vector as long as you don't modify the vector. It is not valid to free this memory using delete.

The whole problem here is that you are storing objects by value in the vector and not by address. Store pointers instead. That way you can add in heap allocated objects, and then loop over the vector and free them when done. That way it only copies pointers, and not objects.

```
vector<Object*> objs;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
    objs.push_back(new Object());
}
for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < vec.size() ; ++i) {
    delete objs[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. It is very clear now. Sorry about not being able to upvote (I don't have enough rep haha).

Answer (score 1):

Doing this

```
my_vect.push_back(*(new Object()));
```

results in these:

1. An object Object is created on the heap.
2. The object's pointer is dereferenced *(..) and is passed as an argument in push_back.
3. **A copy** of this object is created when stored inside the vector.
4. As soon as push_back returns, the initially created Object is still allocated with no one being able to deallocate it, since its pointer is kept nowhere any more. So a memory leak is produced.

As already noted, if you need a vector of "Object" objects you could pass an object created on the stack

```
my_vect.push_back(Object());
```

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. It is very clear now. Sorry about not being able to upvote (I don't have enough rep haha).